# Azure - Web Deployment Task Failed [System.AggregateException - WebToolsException] ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Unable to deploy to Azure App Service. What might be possibly going wrong here?

[image: Web Deployment Task Failed]

10-10-2021 11:07:06
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================

I'm using Visual studio 2022 Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution earlier, but this didn't work in my case, this was actually due to partially deleted publish profile under the properties folder.
So completely clearing (leaving launchSettings.json intact) that and adding profile again helped me resolve this issue.